# Mocha with Vue: Resolution method is overspecified

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vuejs2, mocha.js, vue-resource

this is my test:

```
describe('Documentation Component', () => {
  it('renders a vue instance', (done) => {
    expect(shallow(Documentation).isVueInstance()).toBe(true)
    done()
  })

  it('Gets documentation', async (done) => {
    let wrapper = shallow(Documentation)

    await flushPromises()
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.documentation).toBe('')
    done()
  })
})
```

I followed the guide in the Vue.js docs and I can't get this to work. I need to wait for the docs promise:

```
mounted () {
    // --------------------------------------
    this.$http.get(Config.urls.documentation).then(
      (response) => {
        this.documentation = response.body
      },
      (errorResponse) => {
        EventBridge.$emit('request.error', errorResponse)
        this.documentation = ''
      }
    )
  }
```

The thing is, if I use the "done" function gives this error and without it, it gives this:

```
Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called;
```

I'm not sure what I need to do, just followed the docs. :(

Answer (score 1):

Either use `async` or the `done` argument, don't use both.

Since you are already calling `done()`, you should remove the `async`. So this line:

```
it('Gets documentation', async (done) => {
```

Should be:

```
it('Gets documentation', (done) => {
```

---

If you want to wait for the promises, use the other alternative. Remove `done` and use `async` only:

```
it('Gets documentation', async () => {
    let wrapper = shallow(Documentation)

    await flushPromises()
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.documentation).toBe('')
})
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to wait for the promise to finish. There is another way to do it?

Comment: It, doesn't work :( The test freezes.
In any case, I managed to fix it using a diferent method instead of mounted and sending in a callback.
I think I'll re-work the rest of the code to make it more "testeable"

Thanks for your time :D

Comment: It freezes and timeouts?

Comment: Yep, I'm not sure what happens. I'm kind of new to this testing stuff XD

Comment: I mean, if you get a timeout error, we can try to remedy it by adding some more time for the timeout to happen.